# Recursively rename files in subfolders Windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, recursion, filenames, rename

I have a large number of files in subfolders under a parent folder called C:\Images.

All files have a prefix pattern of exactly the same length, 3 characters, i.e. "[digit][digit]-"

```
01-filename.jpg
55-filename.jpg
82-filename.jpg
```

I have worked out how to strip the prefix from filenames by running a batch file in each subfolder, but I want to run one batch files that will start at the parent folder and recursively step through each subfolder and rename / strip the prefix off each filename.

The code below doesn't work :-( any help would be great :-)

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /r "c:\images\" %%f in (*.jpg) do (
pushd 
set filename=%%f
set filename=!filename:~3!
rename "%%f" "!filename!"
popd
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the filename that doesn't include the path on the second argument to `rename`:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /r "c:\images\" %%f in (*.jpg) do (
    set filename=%%~nxf
    set filename=!filename:~3!
    rename "%%f" "!filename!"
)
```

`%%~nxI` gives both filename and extension.

It may also be a very good idea to check if the file is really needed to be renamed:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /r "c:\images\" %%f in (*.jpg) do (
    set filename=%%~nxf
    if "!filename:~2,1!" == "-" (
        set filename=!filename:~3!
        rename "%%f" "!filename!"
    )
)
```

Finally consider adding a message:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /r "c:\images\" %%f in (*.jpg) do (
    set filename=%%~nxf
    if "!filename:~2,1!" == "-" (
        set filename=!filename:~3!
        echo Renaming %%f to !filename!.
        rename "%%f" "!filename!"
    ) else (
        echo Skipping file %%f.
    )
)
```

And you don't need `pushd` and `popd` for that.